# Position 3 divs, one on the left, two on the right (above and bottom) respectively

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am very sorry if my question or codes are confusing to you. I am trying to Position 3 divs, one on the left, two on the right (above and bottom) respectively. I want it to be like the following image:

[image]

I am using the following codes, and I can get the icon displayed correctly, but the text "ferrari' and ion-checkbox are not displayed similarly as the image attached below. And the div that contains the text 'Some Icons' is not similarly as the image attached below. At first I thought this is simple task and I tried but cannot make this work. I have been stuck for this. Can any CSS expert help me please?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.min.css">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.9/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="width:25%;height:25%;display:inline-block;">
  
  <img style="width: 100%;
    height: auto;" src="https://s10.postimg.org/ar28d6cad/evc03r304.jpg " />
</div>

<div style="width:75%;height:25%;display:inline-block;">
  <b style="width:100%;height:50%;">Ferrari</b>
  
  <!-- Will display some icons in it later-->
  <div style="width:100%;height:50%;">Some Icons</div>
</div>

<div style="height:25%;width:75%;">
  <ion-checkbox>
    Please check me and ETC. !!!
  </ion-checkbox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Ionic's in built grid system by assigning a `row` as a container, and within that row, defining columns. You can do something like this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content >
      <div class="row">
      <div class= "item item-image col col-25">
        <img src="https://s10.postimg.org/ar28d6cad/evc03r304.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class= "list col col-75">
       <div class="item item-text-wrap">
       some text here
      </div>
         <ion-checkbox class="item item-text-wrap item-checkbox-right">
         othet text here
      </ion-checkbox>
      </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

You will need to remove the padding that the rows and columns have by default like so.

```
/* Styles here */
.row,
.col{
  padding:0;
}
```

Working Example http://play.ionic.io/app/296ddd83faf9

Comment: Hi, how can I change a particular row's height?

Answer (score 1):

The Some Icons Box is not displayed because you lost a `"` at the end of your style attribute.

Have a look at the ionic framework docs to wrap your boxes easy: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#grid

Answer (score 0):

You can use float to align the div side by side. Using `display: inline-block;` have some small extra space after them so using exact width won't work. You need to remove that space if you want to achieve it using inline-block property. Here is an article that explains how you can do that. 
https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Or you can use float instead. You need to clear floats that I've done using clearfix css.

```css
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.min.css">
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.9/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container clearfix" style="width:25%;height:25%;float:left;">

  <img style="width: 100%;
    height: auto;" src="https://s10.postimg.org/ar28d6cad/evc03r304.jpg " />
</div>

<div class="clearfix" style="width:75%;height:25%;float:left;">
  <b style="width:100%;height:50%;">Ferrari</b>

  <!-- Will display some icons in it later-->
  <div style="width:100%;height:50%;">Some Icons</div>
</div>

<div style="height:25%;width:75%;">
  <ion-checkbox>
    Please check me and ETC. !!!
  </ion-checkbox>
</div>
```